# thymeleaf template how to link model attribute with <Insert></insert> fiels?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Hello can you please help me to resolve problem:
In my controller i send two dates into model: dateFrom and dateTo
Here is controller code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/transports")
    public String transports(Model model) {
        LOGGER.debug("transports()");
        model.addAttribute("transports", this.transportService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("fuelsMap", getFuelsMap(this.fuelService.findAll()));
        Date dateFrom = new Date();
        model.addAttribute("dateFrom", DateConverter.getDateByString("2020-01-02","yyyy-MM-dd"));
        model.addAttribute("dateTo", DateConverter.getDateByString("2020-01-30","yyyy-MM-dd"));
        return "transports";
    }
```

I need to make link if this attributes to input fields in my thymeleaf template
Goal is to make button that will make href to adress: http://localhost:8081/transports/from/2020-01-02/to/2020-01-30 where 2020-01-02 is dateFrom, 2020-01-30 is dateTo.

now i have this code: is make me url with values that i send from controller, **i dont get how to get values from input fields**

```
<label class="form-control-label" for="dateFrom">Date from</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" type="text" th:attr="value=${#dates.format(dateFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}">

                                <label class="form-control-label" for="field_dateTo">Date to</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="dateTo" id="field_dateTo" type="text" th:attr="value=${#dates.format(dateTo, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}">

                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <a href="transport.html"
                                           th:href="@{|/transports/from/${#dates.format(dateFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}/to/${#dates.format(dateTo, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}|}"
                                           class="btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
                                           title="Edit transport"
                                           data-toggle="tooltip"
                                           data-placement="top">
                                            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                                            <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Search</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

See Thymeleaf's [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) for examples on this.  You can use placeholders like `{from}` and `{to}` in your url, and replace them with your dates.  E.g.:

```
<a href="transport.html"
    th:href="@{/transports/from/{from}/to/{to}(from=${#dates.format(dateFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}, to=${#dates.format(dateTo, 'yyyy-MM-dd')})}"
    class="btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
    title="Edit transport"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-placement="top">
    <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
    <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Search</span>
</a>
```

Comment: how can i take cutom value from " <input class="form-control" name="dateFrom"" ? And place is here: th:href="@{/transports/from/{from}/to/{to}(from=!!! HERE !!!, to=${#dates.format(dateTo, 'yyyy-MM-dd')})}"

Comment: You can't.  If you want to do that, you'll have to use JavaScript to construct that kind of url (as Thymeleaf doesn't have access to form values after the page is rendered).